# Coupon code validation funcanality using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function validate(coupon) {
    var myRe = "LUCKY100";
    if(cvv.value.match(myRe)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('couponerror').innerHTML="Invalid coupon";
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="validate(coupon)">
<label style="width:50px;"><input type="text" name="coupon" class="coupon" title="Enter coupon" o >
</p><span id="usernameError"></span></label>
<input type="button"  value="Submit" />
```

I am new to jquery my question is I need a copon code validation method like I assign a coupon code that is LUCKY100 & if user enter in input type diffrent value it give error message below to input field not alert & if user enter LUCKY100 it gives message coupon applied successfully. Kindly provide me html of this validation and javascript or jquery.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: Where do you get the correct value to compare against when the user types in his input?

Comment: I will assign LUCKY100 in JS or in JQ  @FDavidov

Comment: Hi, you can see code what I have tried @MayankPandey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```js
function validate(coupon) {
    var myRe = "LUCKY100";
    var coupon = myRe.trim();
    var input = document.getElementById('in').value;
    if(input.toUpperCase() == coupon.toUpperCase()) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML="Coupon applied!";
        document.getElementById('err').innerHTML="";
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('err').innerHTML="Invalid coupon";
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML="";
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
#message{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  color:green;
}
#err{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="">
<label style="width:50px;"><input type="text" name="coupon" id="in" class="coupon" title="Enter coupon" >
<span id="usernameError"></span></label>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="validate(coupon)" /></form>

<span id="message"></span>
<span id="err"></span>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: user requested jQuery ... `var input = $('#in')[0].value();` etc please ;)

Comment: Thank @Hitesh, Kindly tell me one more thing that if user enter coupon in sencetive case it should also be applied like Lucky100 or lucky100

Comment: You can make both arguments lower or upper case while checking using toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() methods, I've updated my answer check it

Comment: Thank you very much bro it works perfectly @Hitesh Misro

Answer (score 1):

```js
function validate(coupon) {
    var myRe = "LUCKY100";
    if(cvv.value.match(myRe)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('couponerror').innerHTML="Invalid coupon";
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="validate(coupon)">
<label style="width:50px;"><input type="text" name="coupon" class="coupon" title="Enter coupon" o >
</p><span id="usernameError"></span></label>
<input type="button"  value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the correct value is hardcoded. Assuming that you want a case-insensitive check:

1. Add an input element as:

and in your js:

```
 :
 if (document.getElementById("userInput").value != "undefined") {

     if (document.getElementById("userInput").value.toUpperCase() == "LUCKY100") {

         return true ;
     } else {
         return false ;
 }
 :
```

Comment: Kindly provide me complete JS with html as error message not displaying @FDavidov

Comment: You can deploy a label with an ID and change the value (again using `document.getElementById(...).value = ...`) to update the error message (to null or to the actual message when there is an error).

Comment: user requested jQuery ... `$('#userInput')[0].value().toUpperCase()` please ;)